# Microsoft Excel Runtime Error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

> The extract range has missing or
>   illegal field name.

code follows...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 2 Then
'calculate criteria cell in case calculation mode is manual
  Worksheets("ProductList").Range("C3").Calculate
  Worksheets("SalesData").Range("Table_HESCO") _
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
      CriteriaRange:=Sheets("ProductList").Range("C2:C3"), _
      CopyToRange:=Range("B18:V18"), Unique:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CriteriaRange` and `CopyToRange` headings need to match with the `Table_HESCO` headings

Eg

```
Sub test1()

    Sheets("SalesData").Range("Table_HESCO").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,    CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("ProductList").Range("C2:C3"),   CopyToRange:=Sheets("SalesData").Range("B18:D18"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

takes the filtered data from named range 'Table_HESCO' and places into SalesData with field names in B18:D18 based on criteria on ProductList with field name(s) in C2

[image: Sheets("SalesData").Range("Table_HESCO")]

[image: Sheets("ProductList").Range("C2:C3")]

[image: Sheets("SalesData").Range("B18:D18")]